# Android M sharing chooser filter

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sharing, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have a problem with sharing on Android M and exactly with creating intent chooser with filter. I've create a standard text share intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getSharingText());
return intent;
```

Then I've applied the filter for chooser:

```
List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<>();
List<ResolveInfo> resolves = getActivity().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resolves) {
    String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;

    Intent targetedShareIntent = new Intent(mPromoIntent);
    if (!packageName.equals("com.facebook.katana")
            && !packageName.equals("com.vkontakte.android")) {
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(packageName, resolveInfo.activityInfo.name);
        targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShareIntent.setComponent(componentName));
    }
}

if (targetedShareIntents.isEmpty()) {
    return null;
}
Intent chooser = targetedShareIntents.remove(0);
return Intent.createChooser(chooser, chooserText)
        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
                targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[targetedShareIntents.size()]));
```

And the I've started the standard chooser ChooserActivity using chooser intent

```
startActivity(mAppsChooserIntent);
```

But on Android M it doesn't show chooser, it takes the first intent (in my case bluetooth) and shares with it.
I've looked through the ChooserActivity class, which in Android MNC is much bigger than in Android L and didn't find a solution where.
Does somebody know the answer or it's Android M preview bug?